# Error: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a TestCafe test trying to hit a remote, non-secure (HTTP) URL (for testing purposes), but it is failing with the error:

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"

Is there some TestCafe option for playing nicely with HTTP-based URLs? I have tried using the option --allow-running-insecure-content/allowRunningInsecureContent but it doesn't seem to help.

I also tried extending RequestHook, but when I try to override onRequest() the event parameter is viewed as an "object" type and so it doesn't contain the expected requestOptions property.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: TestCafe has full support for testing HTTP pages. The information in your question is not enough to say why you received this error. Please send the test code that reproduces the error, the tested page URL, and the options you specify when you run TestCafe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I finally tracked down the issue and it had nothing to do with TestCafe. There was a line in our code calling https.get(url) on an insecure (HTTP) URL, which I was able to fix.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.